Two detail tabels with a foreign key to the same master table (User), how to limit a ManyToManyField to see only the subset of the other detail tabel
In Django I have an Order and Contact table that both have a foreignKeyField to the User table, in the Order table I want a ManyToManyField to see only the subset of Contact table records that belong to the same User, instead of the ManyToManyField seeing all of the records of the contact table.
class Contact(models.Model):
    cnt_user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=False, null=True)


class Order(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='order_set')
    ref_code = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=True, null=True)
    ### ManyToManyField should only see subset of contacts that have same user.
    contacts = models.ManyToManyField(Contact, blank=True, limit_choices_to={'cnt_user': user})

The view function that creates or updates an Order record:
def create_or_update_order(request, cur_pk=None, mst_pk=None):

    order = None
    masterpk = None
    verbal = 'New'
    error = None
    sender = None

    if cur_pk:
        print('cur_pk recieved')
        # When Get or Post and jet cur_pk is criterium for edit state
        verbal = 'Edit'
        # If pk is given, get the record object
        try:
            order = Order.objects.get(pk=cur_pk)
            # Haal detail records op
            #if hoedanigheid != 'ParentCurrentNoDetail':
            #     = order.Detail_Subset.all()

        except Order.DoesNotExist:
            pass

    ## When a mst_pk is given
    if mst_pk:
        masterpk = mst_pk
    else:
        ## Check if there is a masterpk
        try:
            if order.user_id:
                masterpk = order.user_id
        except AttributeError:
            pass

    if request.method == 'POST':
        print('in post')
        sender = request.POST.get('ctrl')
        # Beeing in post is criterium for edit state
        verbal = 'Edit'
        form = OrderForm(request.POST, request.FILES, instance=order)
        # If pk is given it is about an update
        if cur_pk:
            print('has pk')
            print(cur_pk)
            if form.is_valid():
                print('orderform is valid')
                form.save()
            else:
                print('orderform is not valid')

        else:
            if form.is_valid():
                order = form.save(commit=False)
                #order.creator = request.user
                order.ordered_date = timezone.now()
                if masterpk:
                    order.user_id = masterpk
                order.save()
            else:
                error = 'Form not valid, new record not saved'
    else:
        print('in get')
        form = OrderForm(instance=order)

    ctrl = {'verbal': verbal, 'masterpk': masterpk, 'error': error, 'from': sender}

    if sender == 'checkout':
        return redirect('core:checkout')
    else:
        return render(request, 'core/create_or_update_order.html', {'form': form, 'ctrl': ctrl })

The urls to this view:
path("create/order/<int:mst_pk>/", order.create_or_update_order, name="create_order"),
path("edit/order/<int:cur_pk>/", order.create_or_update_order, name="edit_order"),

List view for Orders:
def list_by_user_order(request, mst_pk):
    user = None
    orders = None
    verbal = 'List'
    Error = None

    # Get all records
    try:
        user = theUser.objects.get(pk=mst_pk)

    except theUser.DoesNotExist:
        pass

    orders = user.order_set.all()

    ctrl = {'verbal': verbal, 'error': Error, 'masterpk': mst_pk}
    return render(request, 'core/list_order_by_user.html',
           {'ctrl': ctrl, 'orders': orders,
           'user': user})

Url to list view:
path("list_by_theUser/order/<int:mst_pk>/", order.list_by_user_order, name="list_by_theUser_order"),

The order form (for readability some code (fields) ommited:
class OrderForm(forms.ModelForm):
    required_css_class = 'required'

    class Meta:
        model = Order
        fields = (  'ord_contactpersonen',)


I cannot figure out how to set the limit_choices_to parameter or how to use a callable in this case.
In this example ({'cnt_user': user}) django sees user as a "foreignKey object" not a "user object" this results in the following error:
Field 'id' expected a number but got <django.db.models.fields.related.ForeignKey: user>.
To me, "this problem" does not seem to be an uncommon scenario, I am hoping there is a straightforward solution.
Can anybody show me an example of how to this, either by a callable or a Q object or any other way (proxy model maybe)?
Thanks in advance.

please can we see your views.py and your url too?

In my opinion this cannot be solved in the view, I need the form object to express the limited choices, this cannot be tweaked in the view (as far as I know).

You never can tell how seeing the view, urls and or forms.py could help to figure out why you are getting Field 'id' expected a number but got <django.db.models.fields.related.ForeignKey: user>. this line of code error until another Django expert or professional sees it, what I would like to see mate is not entirely your code base rather your Order list view, and detail views. I wish there is another way I can help you, but right now, I am handicapped with little information. You link screenshot the image, edit your questions, and put a link of the code to it using markdown if you can.

there are different approaches to go around this challenge you face in your code including overriding it in your view, and I believe the easiest way to achieve it is through the usage of Q object since I still want to use the limit_choices_to as you wanted. The Q object we shall create will allow you to filter the contacts based on the user's ID in your database. However, we will need to access the user's ID within the limit_choices_to parameter. One way to do this is by using a custom manager method, with this approach as we are going to re-write your entire models.py snippet, we are certain that we have restricted the choices for the contacts field in your Order model's ManyToManyField.
your code re-written version:

from django.conf import settings
from django.db import models
from django.db.models import Q

class ContactManager(models.Manager):


    def get_queryset(self) -> models.QuerySet:
        """ This method overrides the default get_queryset() method provided by the base
             models.Manager class. It returns a QuerySet 
            of objects based on the specified filter conditions"""

        queryset = super().get_queryset().\
            filter(user_id = models.F('order__user_id'))
        return queryset

        # NB : filter(user_id=models.F('order__user_id')) above, filters the queryset based on 
        #  the condition that the user_id field should be equal to the value of models.F('order__user_id')


class Contact(models.Model):
    cnt_user = models.ForeignKey(
            settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
            on_delete=models.CASCADE
            )
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=False, null=True)

    objects = ContactManager()

    def __str__(self) -> str:
        return self.cnt_user.username
    
  


class Order(models.Model):

    user = models.ForeignKey(
                settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
                on_delete=models.CASCADE, 
                related_name='order_set'
                )
    
    ref_code = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=True, null=True)

    ### ManyToManyField should only see subset of contacts that have same user.
    contacts = models.ManyToManyField(
                    Contact, 
                    limit_choices_to=Q(
                    user_id=models.F('cnt_user_id'),
                    blank=True
                    ))
  
    # a human readable object setup instead of the data  been # 
    # returned in as object1, object2 etc. in your admin panel.
    
     def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username
    



Please, pardon me for so many comments, it is just to make it clearer as much as possible, and don't forget to delete them if you wish. Goodluck mate.

Sorry it took me so long to get back at your solution.
I have been “playing around with your code” but somehow I can't get it to work, I don't get error messages but I also don't get any results in my "manytomanyfield" in the form.

Thank you for your response @Blaisemart.
My understanding of the matter now is that my problem originates from the fact that models are classes and thus everything
concerning what they initially show can only be handled in the definition of the class, so it is not possible "fly in a dynamic parameter” to change what the model shows initially, or for that case also what the “limit_choices_to” parameter shows initially.

Seems there is a way to set the query of a foreign key (or manytomany) choice field in the view after all!
I am surprised that I did not find this answer sooner.
Anser here:
How do I filter ForeignKey choices in a Django ModelForm?
In my case:
(In the view:)
form.fields["contacts"].queryset = contact.objects.filter(cnt_user_id=order.user_id)

